# Modifying a.e decreasing function to an everywhere decreasing function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function and $g: \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ be a locally-integrable function such that
\begin{equation}
f(b)-f(a) \leq -\int_a^b g(x)dx
\end{equation}
holds for almost every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $b \in (a,\infty)$.

This seems to me in a sense that $f(x)$ is monotone-decreasing "almost everywhere".

Now, my question:

is it possible to modify $f$ on a set of measure zero such that the above inequality holds for "all" $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$?

This issues looks more subtle than expected.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Can't we just let $A=\{a\in\mathbb{R}\mid \text{not all }b\text{ }\ldots\}$ and just modify $\tilde{f}(a)=\lim_{b\to a+, b\notin A}f(b)$ for $a\in A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}: \text{ for all } b > a, f(b) - f(a) \le - \int_a^b g(x) dx\}.$

For $a \not \in \mathcal{A}$ and $b > a$ with $b \in \mathcal{A}$, define
$$
f_b^*(a) = f(b) + \int_a^b g(x) dx.
$$
Note that for $c \ge b$ with $c \in \mathcal{A}$,
$$f_c^*(a) - f_b^*(a) = f(c) - f(b) + \int_b^c g(x) dx \le 0.$$

As a result, on $\mathcal{A} \cap (a, \infty)$ the map $b \mapsto f_b^*(a)$ is decreasing.

As a result, we can define
$$
f^*(a) = \begin{cases}
f(a), a \in \mathcal{A}\\
\sup_{b \in \mathcal{A}, b> a} f_b^*(a).
\end{cases}
$$
Checking that this definition satisfies the desired inequality is essentially a lot of simple case checking. In what follows, I will always have $a < b$.

If both $a,b$ are in $\mathcal{A}$, the desired inequality is true by assumption.

If $b \in \mathcal{A}$ and $a \not \in \mathcal{A}$ then choose $c \in (a,b)$ such that $c \in \mathcal{A}$ (which is possible since the complement of $\mathcal{A}$ has measure $0$). Then
$$f^*(b) - f^*(a) = f(b) - f^*(a) \le f(b) - f_c^*(a) = f(b) - f(c) - \int_a^c g(x) dx \le - \int_a^b g(x) dx.$$

If $a \in \mathcal{A}$ and $b \not \in \mathcal{A}$ then
$$f^*(b) - f^*(a) = \sup_{c > b, c \in \mathcal{A}} f(c) - f(a) + \int_b^c g(x) dx \le \sup_{c > b} \Bigg ( - \int_a^c g(x) dx + \int_b^c g(x) dx \Bigg )$$
which implies the desired inequality.

Finally if $a \not \in \mathcal{A}$, $b \not \in \mathcal{A}$,
$$f^*(b) - f^*(a) = \sup_{c > b, c \in \mathcal{A}} \Bigg ( f(c) + \int_b^c g(x) dx \Bigg ) - \sup_{d > a, d \in \mathcal{A}} \Bigg ( f(d) + \int_a^d g(x) dx \Bigg ).$$

Pick $d \in (a,b) \cap \mathcal{A}$. Then for each $c$ in the set over which we take the first supremum on the right hand side, we have
$$ f(c) + \int_b^c g(x) dx - f(d) - \int_a^d g(x) dx \le - \int_d^c g(x) dx + \int_b^c g(x) dx - \int_a^d g(x) dx.$$

Since the right hand side is nothing but $-\int_a^b g(x) dx$ this implies the desired bound.

Comment: Thank you! If we just have $f(b) \leq f(a)$ for almost every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $b \in (a,\infty)$, can we modify your argument somehow? Could you please help me once more?

Comment: @Keith maybe I miss something because I haven't thought about this for a while, but isn't that just the special case $g=0$ in the above?

Comment: Ooops... yes you are absolutely correct. Thank you!